# authorization windows phone and problems with user session

Tags: c#, windows-phone, authorization, usersession

I am developing an application on windows phone. Having problems with authorization. Here's the thing.
When I send a login request to the server with a username and password if they correct the server returns me id user and redirects to another page. But if you press the "back" button, the app sends you to a page with input a login / password that was in the beginning. The question is this. How to save the user's session? To return when he remained in the system?You may need to keep id user to an IsolatedStorage, and how the work with him? Or perhaps there are other solutions to this problem?
I would welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked many questions here..

For storing the values(userid,password etc.) you can use [IsolatedStorageSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.95).aspx) .

The code given below shows how you can store values from  IsolatedStorageSettings

To store

```
IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

  userSettings["userId"] = "213213";
```

To retrieve

```
  string id= (string)userSettings["userId"];
```

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/12269/) its explained how you can use `NavigationService` to remove back stack entry (for handling "back" button issue)